# MySQL Combining 2 Queries - Inner Join Issue

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a subquery into a select as follows:

```
select ProductID,
       ProductName,
       concat((UnitsInStock / (select sum(UnitsInStock) from products))*100, '%')
       as Percent_of_total_units_in_stock
from products
order by ProductID;

/*
This query returns the same result as query above.
Here 3119 is hardcoded whereas query above uses
subquery to calculate 3119 on the fly.
*/
select ProductID,
       ProductName,
       concat((UnitsInStock / 3119)*100, '%')
       as Percent_of_total_units_in_stock
from products
order by ProductID;
```

The query runs fine expect for the 3 lines that are starting with '--'. Note: this is just to indicate the issues - wouldn't included this in live query.

I vaguely understand that I'm trying to run an Inner Query with Left Joins and this doesn't work. If this could be explained better to me that would be great.

Question: Is there a way to structure this query so I can run the 2 together? I've tried a couple of configurations and I always get the MySQL error:

```
Unknown column 'a.receiver' in 'on clause'
Error code 1054.
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are refering to the wrong alias in the sub query. The commented code states:

```
FROM messages AS aa
JOIN users AS bb ON aa.sender=bb.userid
LEFT JOIN blocked AS cc ON cc.requester=aa.sender AND cc.receiver = a.receiver
LEFT JOIN blocked AS dd ON dd.receiver=aa.receiver AND dd.requester = a.receiver
```

The `messages` table in the sub query has the alias `aa`. You are using `a` as the alias in the out query. So I would think that this is a mistake and should be like this:

```
FROM messages AS aa
JOIN users AS bb ON aa.sender=bb.userid
LEFT JOIN blocked AS cc ON cc.requester=aa.sender AND cc.receiver = aa.receiver
LEFT JOIN blocked AS dd ON dd.receiver=aa.receiver AND dd.requester = aa.receiver
```

Comment: np. Glad to help